# Python - Using data from scraped web data

Tags: python, list

i'm new here, just started to learn Python 2 days ago, i just made my first program, half done, i need help with the rest please i've tried evrything i could but i'm struggling.

the program is about web **scraping** a currency (name and value) then use the data to select a specific currency, display it + value then enter a specific Alert_value, if the Alert_value is reached then i get notification.

i could scrape the data using BS4 but i couldn't use it as individual data Currency + it's value, no idea if i have to use it as list  or other but i have tried list but my 2 days of experience didn't help :D
the whole Currency data is index[0] i think the problem is that i couldn't make a list out of the Currency name data, index[1] is out of range means that 150 currency name is at index[0].

Annyone can help me please how to put the data of both Currency names and value, and how to select each one individually to display it, please use simple words when explaining i'm just starting. Thank you.

Some of the Code :  name is currency name and price is the currency price

```
for container in containers:
    name_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"tv-screener__symbol"})
    name = name_container[0].text
    title_container = container.findAll("td", {"class":"tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big"})
    price = title_container[2].text
    # print(str(name)  + " : "  + price)

    Xt=[name,price]
    print(Xt)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it would help if you could share samples of the data, the inputs and expected outputs

Comment: FYI it's scraping (and scrape, scraped, scraper) not scrapping. Scrapping means throwing away like rubbish, as does 'to scrap'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi & welcome @HannibalB!

I am a new contributor myself, so unfortunately I cannot comment yet. As far as I understand correctly, you would like to query a currency name - e.g. Nexo - and have the respective value displayed.

Python offers many different data types, all of which are useful for different purposes. In your case, I would suggest a [dictionary](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/dictionary-python?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=898687156&utm_adgroupid=48947256715&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=229765585183&utm_targetid=dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=1010826&gclid=CjwKCAjw9aiIBhA1EiwAJ_GTSgRLbuwsgIO1ivwj4-oj-dX1HO3yBf0D0mjU8vDAJgcJhGwdrCXy2BoC0c0QAvD_BwE). Check out the link, if you would like to know more.

What you could do, is adjust the code slightly (I am assuming here that it already works as intended):

```
Dictionary = {}

for container in containers:
   name_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"tv-screener__symbol"})
   name = name_container[0].text
   title_container = container.findAll("td", {"class":"tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big"})
   price = title_container[2].text
   # print(str(name)  + " : "  + price)

   Dictionary[name] = price
```

You can now simply access the elements in the dictionary like so:

```
Dictionary['Nexo']
```

This will then display the price/value that is stored under the so called `dictionary key`, which in this case is `Nexo`. In case you prefer `pandas.DataFrame`, you can easily convert a dictionary into [one](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). Check out the link.

You might have also thought about appending a `DataFrame` directly. Even though I am not an expert, I would advise against that. A `DataFrame` is quite a heavy data structure and it is usually more efficient to convert you data into a `DataFrame` as a final step.

Comment: thank you so much, you made my day i'm so gratful, can i ask fiew more questions please ?

Comment: @HannibalB, if you have other questions, I suggest that you browse e.g. SO first. If your search does not return any useful solutions, please open a new question. This also helps others to find solutions to related problems and keeps SO organized. Also, if my answer helps, please mark it as useful.